# How can I get individual test iteration results from a load test?

Tags: load-testing, visualstudio

In a Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Test project, how can I look at the (Test log) results of individual test runs from a load test?

If my load test experiences any errors, I can go to the Errors table and click on any of the error counts, and I am presented with a "Load Test Errors" list of all the failed test iterations. I can then go to the "Details" column at the right edge of this table/list, and click on a "Test log" link for any test, and I can see the details of every request and response from that test iteration.

How can I do the same thing, view results of individual test iterations, when my load test has zero errors? How can I view the 'Test logs' of test iterations that pass?

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/billbar/2009/06/08/vsts-2010-load-test-feature-saving-test-logs/
Use the setting "Save log frequency for completed tests" = 1. It will log for every iteration.

Comment: There is a related setting which is the maximum number of logs that will be saved, its default value is 200.